# Good method to substitute end-lines '\n' into spaces in a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I have an error message that spans across multiple (2-3) lines. I want to catch it and embed in a warning. I think that substituting new-lines into spaces is ok.

My question is, which method is the best practice. I know this is not the best kind of question, but I want to code it properly. I also might be missing something. So far I have came up with 3 methods:

1. string.replace()
2. regular expression
3. string.translate()

I was leaning towards string.translate(), however after reading how it works, I think it's an overkill to covert every character into itself except '\n'. Regexp also seems like an overkill for such a simple task.

Is there any other method designated to it, or should I pick up one of the aforementioned? I care about portability and robustness more than speed but it is still somewhat relevant.

Comment: By "substituting new-lines into spaces", do you mean inserting line breaks to wrap long text lines, or do you mean replacing line breaks in the original text with space characters?

Comment: `'\n' -> ' '` sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `replace` method:

```
>>> "\na".replace("\n", " ")
' a'
>>>
```

It is the simplest solution.  Using Regex is overkill and also means you have to import.  `translate` is a little better, but still doesn't give anything that `replace` doesn't (except more typing of course).

`replace` should run faster too.

Comment: I thought initially that translate would be faster than searching for substrings. But now I don't think so. Could you comment on that an the portability to Windows and Unicode, any troubles expected going there?

Comment: @luk32 - None that I know of.  As its name suggests, `translate` is for translating multiple characters (very nice when converting text between different languages).  However, if you just want to replace one, a newline, with another, a space, then using `replace` is by far the best solution.  It's short, simple, fast, and works anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to leave all these implementation details up to the python implementation you could do:

```
s = "This\nis\r\na\rtest"
print " ".join(s.splitlines())
# prints: This is a test
```

Note:

> This method uses the *universal newlines* approach to splitting lines.

Which means:

> **universal newlines** A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention `'\n'`, the Windows convention `'\r\n'`, and the old Macintosh convention `'\r'`. See PEP 278 and PEP 3116, as well as `str.splitlines()` for an additional use.

A benefit of splitting lines over replacing linefeeds is that you can filter out lines you don't need, i.e. to avoid clutter in your log. For example, if you have this output of `traceback.format_exc()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

And you need to add only the last line(s) to your log:

```
import traceback
try:
    1/0
except: # of course you wouldn't catch exceptions like this in real code
    print traceback.format_exc().splitlines()[-1]
    # prints: ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join
- http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines
- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 1):

This is another fast/portable option. It is more or less the same as replace but less readable

```
errMsg = """Something went wrong
            This message is long"""

" ".join(errMsg.splitlines())
```

With timing results although I guarantee this will be different based on message length

```
>>> s = """\
' '.join('''Something went wrong
            This message is long'''.splitlines())"""

>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000)
0.06071170746817329

>>> q = """'''\
Something went wrong
This message is long'''.replace("\\n",' ')"""

>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=q, number=100000)
0.049164684830429906
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of it. But I think it does more a lot more work than `replace`. +1 for the creativity though.

Comment: Why do you split to join fust after instead of only replacing... So much work for a simple operation.

Comment: Just thinking outside the box. Not sure how different it is for timing or memory. Someone else feel free to check

Answer (score 0):

This should work on both Windows and Linux.

```
string.replace('\r\n', ' ').replace('\n', ' ')
```